# High AUC but bad predictions with imbalanced data

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, auc, lightgbm

I am  trying to build a classifier with LightGBM on a very imbalanced dataset. Imbalance is in the ratio `97:3`, i.e.:

```
Class

0    0.970691
1    0.029309
```

Params I used and the code for training is as shown below.

```python
lgb_params = {
        'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
        'objective': 'binary',
        'metric':'auc',
        'learning_rate': 0.1,
        'is_unbalance': 'true',  #because training data is unbalance (replaced with scale_pos_weight)
        'num_leaves': 31,  # we should let it be smaller than 2^(max_depth)
        'max_depth': 6, # -1 means no limit
        'subsample' : 0.78
    }

# Cross-validate
cv_results = lgb.cv(lgb_params, dtrain, num_boost_round=1500, nfold=10, 
                    verbose_eval=10, early_stopping_rounds=40)

nround = cv_results['auc-mean'].index(np.max(cv_results['auc-mean']))
print(nround)

model = lgb.train(lgb_params, dtrain, num_boost_round=nround)


preds = model.predict(test_feats)

preds = [1 if x >= 0.5 else 0 for x in preds]
```

I ran CV to get the best model and best round. I got 0.994 AUC on CV and similar score in Validation set.

But when I am predicting on the test set I am getting very bad results. I am sure that the train set is sampled perfectly.

What parameters are needed to be tuned.? What is the reason for the problem.? Should I resample the dataset such that the highest class is reduced.?

Comment: what is the exact code you use for prediction?

Comment: I will update the question to show code now

Comment: pls include also a (short) sample of your data & predictions, as well as any info related to the class imbalance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that, despite the extreme class imbalance in your dataset, you are still using the "default" threshold of 0.5 when deciding the final hard classification in

```
preds = [1 if x >= 0.5 else 0 for x in preds]
```

This should **not** be the case here.

This is a rather big topic, and I strongly suggest you do your own research (try googling for *threshold* or *cut off probability imbalanced data*), but here are some pointers to get you started...

From a relevant answer at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6067/does-an-unbalanced-sample-matter-when-doing-logistic-regression) (emphasis added):

> Don't forget that you should be **thresholding intelligently** to make predictions. It is not always best to predict 1 when the model probability is greater 0.5. Another threshold may be better. To this end you should look into the Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) curves of your classifier, not just its predictive success with a default probability threshold.

From a relevant academic paper, [Finding the Best Classification Threshold in Imbalanced Classification](http://iranarze.ir/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/E2281.pdf):

> *2.2. How to set the classification threshold for the testing set*
>
> Prediction
> results
> are
> ultimately
> determined
> according
> to
> prediction
> probabilities.
> The
> threshold
> is
> typically
> set
> to
> 0.5.
> If
> the
> prediction
> probability
> exceeds
> 0.5,
> the
> sample
> is
> predicted
> to
> be
> positive;
> otherwise,
> negative.
> However,
> 0.5
> is
> not
> ideal
> for
> some
> cases,
> particularly
> for
> imbalanced
> datasets.

The post [Optimizing Probability Thresholds for Class Imbalances](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/blog/2014/2/1/lw6har9oewknvus176q4o41alqw2ow) from the (highly recommended) Applied Predictive Modeling blog is also relevant.

Take home lesson from all the above: AUC is seldom enough, but the ROC *curve* itself is often your best friend...

---

On a more general level regarding the role of the threshold itself in the classification process (which, according to my experience at least, many practitioners get wrong), check also the [Classification probability threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312119/classification-probability-threshold) thread (and the provided links) at Cross Validated; key point:

> the statistical component of your exercise ends when you output a probability for each class of your new sample. Choosing a threshold beyond which you classify a new observation as 1 vs. 0 is not part of the *statistics* any more. It is part of the *decision* component.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will check those resources. I have also tried different thresholds before but the predictions were not that good.

Comment: @SreeramTP Sure, a 97:3 imbalance is almost by definition a tough problem, not amenable to easy or straightforward solutions. But arguably you now have learned something new, i.e. that the choice of the threshold itself is an issue...

Comment: yeah I have. I was exploring the possibilities of XGboost on this data. It produces similar AUC on CV and on the same validation set. The test predictions are much better than the `lgb` predictions even when I keep threshold at `0.5`

Comment: @SreeramTP yes, the classifier performance itself is an issue orthogonal to the threshold choice (i.e. it's always better to start from more accurate predictions)