# In Classification, what is the difference between the test accuracy and the AUC score?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, auc

I am working on a classification-based project, and I am evaluating different ML models based on their training accuracy, testing accuracy, confusion matrix, and the AUC score. I am now stuck in understanding the difference between the scores I get by calculating accuracy of a ML model on the test set (X_test), and the AUC score.

If I am correct, both metrics calculate how well a ML model is able to predict the correct class of previously unseen data. I also understand that for both, the higher the number, the better, for as long as the model is not over-fit or under-fit.

Assuming a ML model is neither over-fit nor under-fit, what is the difference between test accuracy score and the AUC score?

I don't have a background in math and stats, and pivoted towards data science from business background. Therefore, I will appreciate an explanation a business person can understand.

Comment: I recommend reading [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/807), it's really well written and should be able to clear it up for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both terms quantify the quality of a classification model, however, the accuracy quantifies a single manifestation of the variables, which means it describes a single [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix). The `AUC (area under the curve)` represents the trade-off between the `true-positive-rate (tpr)` and the `false-positive-rate (fpr)` in multiple confusion matrices, that are generated for different `fpr` values for the same classifier. 
A confusion matrix is of the form:

[image]

1) The accuracy is a measure for a single confusion matrix and is defined as:
[image: accuracy = (TP+TN)/(TP+FP+TN+FN)]

where tp=true-positives, tn=true-negatives, fp=false-positives and fn=false-negatives (the amount of each).

2) The `AUC` measures the `area under the ROC (receiver operating characteristic)`, that is the `trade-off` curve between the `true-positive-rate` and the `false-positive-rate`. For each choice of the false-positive-rate (fpr) threshold,the true-positive-rate (tpr) is determined. I.e, for a given classifier a fpr of 0, 0.1, 0.2 and so fourth is accepted, and for each fpr it's dependent tpr is evaluated.  Therefore, you get a function *tpr(fpr)* that maps the interval [0,1] onto the same interval, because both rates are defined in those intervals. The area under this line is called the AUC, that is between 0 and 1, whereby a random classification is expected to yield an AUC of 0.5.

[image]
[image]

The AUC, as it is the area under the curve, is defined as:

[image]

However, in real (and finite) applications, the `ROC` is a step function and the AUC is determined by a weighted sum these levels.

Graphics are from [Borgelt's Intelligent Data Mining Lecture](http://www.borgelt.net/teach/ida.html).

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! One follow-up question; when I am evaluating the performance of classification algorithms, are you saying that the AUC score is a better of a metric to rely on than the accuracy score? My slight confusion is that some of my models differ in AUC and test accuracy scores. In this case, I wonder if I should prioritize the model that has a higher test accuracy or AUC score. Thank you!

Comment: @Arsik36 it's not that simple; in order to get the accuracy you need to define a specific *threshold* (see [Predict classes or class probabilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367755/predict-classes-or-class-probabilities)), while AUC measure the performance across a whole range of such thresholds. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104129/getting-a-low-roc-auc-score-but-a-high-accuracy/47111246#47111246) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51190809/high-auc-but-bad-predictions-with-imbalanced-data/51192702#51192702) for more details.